# Невозможно удалить папку с атрибутом "Для чтения" Python

Tags: python, ос, chmod

Хочу удалить папку, в которой есть файлы с атрибутом "Только для чтения". При этом, я пытаюсь убрать у папки этот атрибут, но не выходит. Даже при помощи итерации и поэтапным изменением типа чтения для каждого объекта папки, всё равно не выходит её удалить, выходит такая ошибка:

`PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'путь к папке/файлу папки'`

Как удалить всё содержимое папки, если некоторые её объекты имеют значение "Только для чтения"?

Вот пример кода

```
                for obj in os.listdir('Путь к папке'):
                    os.chmod('Путь к папке' + obj, stat.S_IXUSR)
                    os.remove('Путь к папке' + obj)
```

или вот:

```
            os.chmod('Путь к папке', stat.S_IRGRP)
            shutil.rmtree('Путь к папке')
```

К слову, с одиночными файлами всё работает, но вот с папками вообще нет. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def del_readonly(action, name, exc):
    os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
    os.remove(name)

shutil.rmtree(path, onerror=del_readonly)
```

Если у `shutil.rmtree` не получится удалить что-то, то вызовется функция `del_readonly`, которая уже в ручном режиме поставит атрибут разрешающий запись и удалит этот объект.

Comment: Вроде всё работает, но теперь появляется ошибка, если я хочу скопировать папку из директории, в которой находится файл в другую директорию, вот такая вот ошибка: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'path'`